# Всплывающее окно на определенной кнопке в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Я еще новичок в JavaScript с React и пока не совсем понимаю как решать данную проблему. У меня есть определенный список который отображается методом **map** из сервера занесенная в отдельную компоненту **Orders**, у этого списка имеется кнопка **button** в компоненте **Orders**, кнопок может быть неограниченное количество в зависимости от того сколько данных выгружаемых из сервера в **JSON**. При клике по какой-нибудь кнопке у меня на ней должно отображаться всплывающее(модальное) окно функционал которого прописан в функции **handleModal**, находящийся в компоненте **Orders**, но всплывающее окно отображается на всех кнопках в блоках при клике. Как мне в этом случае изменить код так, чтобы всплывающее окно отображалось на той на которую я нажал. Догадываюсь, что что-то наверное надо делать со стейтом и пропсами, но не понимаю как осуществить. Для понимания прикрепляю **JSX** компоненты **AllOrders** и вынесенной компоненты **Orders**, а также результат при нажатии кнопки откликнуться **Test** отображается на всех кнопках, а должен лишь на той которая была нажата[image: Всплывающее сообщение Test]

Главная компонента **AllOrder**

```
class AllOrder extends React.Component{
    render(){   
return(
    <>
        <section className={s.orders}>
            <div className={s.orders__container}>
                <h1 className={s.orders__title}>Все заказы</h1>
                <form  className={s.orders__form}>
                
                <input className={s.orders__input} type="date" placeholder="Срок до:" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Срок до:"/>
                                    
                <input className={s.orders__input} type="text" placeholder="Стоимость от:" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Только цифры"/>
                
                <input className={s.orders__input} type="text" placeholder="Стоимость до:" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Только цифры"/>
                
                    <select name="" id="" className={s.orders__region}>
                        <option value="" required>Регион</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="" id="" className={s.orders__city}>
                        <option value="" required>Мой город</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="" id="" className={s.orders__service}>
                        <option value="" required>Услуга</option>
                    </select>
                    
                    
                    <input className={s.submit} type="submit" value="Найти"/>
                    <br/>
                    <div className={s.orders__label}>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
        <Orders/>
    </>
);

}
}

export default AllOrder;
```

Вынесенная компонента **Orders**

```
class Orders extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            col: 0,
            data2: {},
            isFetching: true,
            error: null,
            showModal: false
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('http://79.174.13.220:8080/api/orderEntities')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res2Json => this.setState({col:1, data2: res2Json, isFetching: false}))
    }
    handleModal = () => {
        this.setState({showModal: !this.state.showModal})
    }
    render(){
        const {col, data2, isFetching, error } = this.state;
        if (isFetching) return <div>...Loading</div>;
    return(
        <section className={s.execution}>
                {col ? data2["_embedded"]["orderEntities"].map((item, index) => (
                    <div className={s.execution__container}>
                        <div key={item.id} className={s.execution__box}>
                            <div className={s.execution__info}>
                                <div className={s.execution__list}>
                                    <p className={s.execution__services}>Услуга:</p>
                                    <p className={s.execution__services}>Срок исполнения: до 30.09.2020</p>
                                    <p className={s.execution__services}>Стоимость: {item.cost} Р</p>
                                </div>
                                <p className={s.execution__name}>Название: <span>{item.title}</span></p>
                                <div className={s.execution__description}>{item.description}</div>
                                <p className={s.execution__user}>Заказчик:  <a href="#" className="execution__link"></a> <img src="https://s8.********************/uploads/images/2020/11/6ef562d4767cba575a5ac931c26e6bdb.png" alt="" /></p>
                            </div>
                            <div className={s.execution__info}>
                                <button id={index} onClick={this.handleModal} className={s.execution__button}>откликнуться</button>
                                {this.state.showModal && <Modal handleModal={this.handleModal} /> }
                                <p className={s.execution__participants}>0 участников</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))
                    : <p className={s.execution__order}>У Вас ещё пока нет заказов</p>
                }
            </section>
    )
}
}
export default Orders
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В чем у вас проблема, стейт общий для всех модалок, поэтому они все сразу и открываются. Нужно что бы у каждой кнопки/модалки был свой стейт, тогда будет работать как вы хотите.

Создайте компонент OrderItem в который вынесите:

```
<div className={s.execution__container}>
                        <div key={item.id} className={s.execution__box}>
                            <div className={s.execution__info}>
                                <div className={s.execution__list}>
                                    <p className={s.execution__services}>Услуга:</p>
                                    <p className={s.execution__services}>Срок исполнения: до 30.09.2020</p>
                                    <p className={s.execution__services}>Стоимость: {item.cost} Р</p>
                                </div>
                                <p className={s.execution__name}>Название: <span>{item.title}</span></p>
                                <div className={s.execution__description}>{item.description}</div>
                                <p className={s.execution__user}>Заказчик:  <a href="#" className="execution__link"></a> <img src="https://s8.********************/uploads/images/2020/11/6ef562d4767cba575a5ac931c26e6bdb.png" alt="" /></p>
                            </div>
                            <div className={s.execution__info}>
                                <button id={index} onClick={this.handleModal} className={s.execution__button}>откликнуться</button>
                                {this.state.showModal && <Modal handleModal={this.handleModal} /> }
                                <p className={s.execution__participants}>0 участников</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

и туда же вынесите логику и стейт отвечающий за модалку:

```
onstructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showModal: false
        }
    }
handleModal = () => {
        this.setState({showModal: !this.state.showModal})
    }
```